# ¿Cómo comparar valores obtenidos con el fetchone()? Python

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente problema:

Adquiero desde una base de datos con el método "fetchone()" a un dato X que inserté con "input()" y busqué con "select...". Ahora, al guardar en mi variable el dato buscado y usar un operador de comparación ("==, !=, etc"), me sale con que no coinciden. Si utilizo un operador de membresía ("in, not in") y los resultados coinciden, me funciona, pero si no existe el valor introducido, me salta un error. Dejo acá lo mencionado.

Código usando operadores de comparación:

```
introducir=input("Introducir: ")
mycursor.execute("SELECT nombre FROM cuentas WHERE nombre='%s'" % (introducir))
nombre=mycursor.fetchone()

#Si uso un dato que existe
if introducir!=nombre:
    print("No es")
    print(nombre)
else:
    print("Logrado")
    print(nombre)
```

Resultado:

```
Introducir: Gerald
No es
('Gerald',)
```

Otro código:

```
introducir=input("Introducir: ")
mycursor.execute("SELECT nombre FROM cuentas WHERE nombre='%s'" % (introducir))
nombre=mycursor.fetchone()

#Si uso un dato que NO existe
if introducir!=nombre:
    print("No es")
    print(nombre)
else:
    print("Logrado")
    print(nombre)
```

Resultado (lo esperado):

```
Introducir: dsadsad
No es
None
```

Ahora, usando operadores de membresía:

```
introducir=input("Introducir: ")
mycursor.execute("SELECT nombre FROM cuentas WHERE nombre='%s'" % (introducir))
nombre=mycursor.fetchone()

#Si uso un dato que existe
if introducir not in nombre:
    print("No es")
    print(nombre)
else:
    print("Logrado")
    print(nombre)
```

Resultado:

```
Introducir: Gerald
Logrado
('Gerald',)
```

Poniendo un resultado que no existe:

```
Introducir: ggdd

Se produjo una excepción: TypeError
argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Ya he intentando poner el tuple (porque lo adquirido automáticamente se adentra en un tuple) como un string o usando "fetchall()" y comparado y siempre hay un error en ellos. No sé cómo hacer.

Lo que quiero es comparar si el dato introducido está o es igual al dato adquirido desde la base de datos. Si no lo es, que me haga un "while" hasta que ingrese un usuario existente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `fetchone()` devuelve una tupla, al comparar una tupla con el string nombre,  te dice que no son iguales, por que no lo son.

Tienes que acceder a clave de la tupla para poder comparar. Intenta lo siguiente:

```
if nombre != None:
    if introducir != nombre[0]:
```

La segunda opción que usas `not in` funciona porque el string que buscas si que está en la tulpla.

Comment: Ya hice primera opción que me colocaste y funciona si el dato existe. Pero sino es así entonces me devuelve un error de "Se produjo una excepción: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".

Comment: Claro, no puedes comparar algo que no existe. Actualizo la respuesta para añadir la comprobación. Puedes añadir en el else: correspondiente el comportamiento que deseas si el nombre no existe.